# Dynamically send pdf attached to post with contact form 7

Tags: email, plugin-contact-form-7

I'm trying to send a dynamic pdf that is attached to a post via the plugin contact form 7.

I assume I need to use the hook:

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail','send_pdf');
```

As it's been the hook I've seen used most commonly when looking for a solution.

Here's what I have, I've just been trying with a test pdf with an absolute url first:

```
function send_pdf( $cf7 ) {
    if ($cf7->id==741){
        $cf7->uploaded_files = array ( 'pdf' => get_template_directory().'/test.pdf' );
    }
}
```

Now if I understand this correctly, if the contact form id is correct, and I have `[pdf]` in the mail2 "file attachment" field, then that pdf should send via email to the person who has submitted their details?

For me though this isn't working, I get the email but with no attachment.

Is there something I'm missing here or perhaps know of another method that works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this instead.  There was some internal restructuring in CF7 3.9.

`add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail','send_pdf');`

```
function send_pdf( $cf7 ) {
    $id = $cf7->id();
    if ($id==741){
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        $submission->add_uploaded_file('pdf', get_template_directory().'/test.pdf');
    }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: You beautiful person, works great. Oh you might want to add a slash before test.pdf that was a typo on my behalf. Might confuse people who use it :)

Comment: Good call on the typo.  Glad it works!

Comment: I don't suppose you know why that test.pdf url worked by a url like /wp-content/uploads/2015/01/test.pdf does not? Something to do with plugin permissions?

Comment: Are you hard coding the URL?

Comment: I think you need an absolute path.  You might try get_home_path();  I can't test right now but let me know if it works.

Comment: See also https://wordpress.org/support/topic/sending-an-attachment-using-contact-form-7 it helped me a lot

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Sends the email out no worries, but nothing attached on it

Comment: As this seems to be an accepted answer, why would I be getting the error; `Uncaught Error: Call to private method WPCF7_Submission::add_uploaded_file()`?

Comment: Chris Pink, this changed with the last CF7 update - I'm trying to find a new method right now.  :-(

Comment: @ChrisPink You have to combine this functionality with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48189650/2757809