# Attaching a pdf to Contact Form 7 e-mail via functions.php

Tags: php, email, plugin-contact-form-7, pdf

I'm trying to attach pdf files to an e-mail manually and I did some research on the topic and found this [code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175872/dynamically-send-pdf-attached-to-post-with-contact-form-7):

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail','send_pdf');

function send_pdf( $cf7 ) {
    $id = $cf7->id();
    if ($id==2399){
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        $submission->add_uploaded_file('pdf', get_template_directory().'/pdf/test.pdf');
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that after the email is sent, the file and the folder are deleted but nothing is attached. I'm using a theme and a child theme, and the folder is put in the main theme directory. Anyone ideas?

Comment: Check [Dynamically attaching file to Contact Form 7 E-Mail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68387718/1287812)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found what's been missing in the code. You have to add this also:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_components', 'mycustom_wpcf7_mail_components' );

function mycustom_wpcf7_mail_components( $components ) {
    $components['attachments'][] = get_template_directory().'/pdf/test.pdf';

    return $components;
}
```

Now everything is working fine and the file is attached to email without the need to add fields in the contact form.

Comment: I tried your code and didnt work for me. I placed it in Functions.php

Comment: I wnats to send this attchment only in user email but not idea how to manage condition here?

Comment: This method only 'kind of' works - if your form also has 'file upload' fields it won't send the uploaded files, just the file you're attaching here.